# What is the proper way to handle errors that occur within IServerChannelSink.ProcessMessage?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, tcp, .net-remoting

I've been getting an occasional exception thrown (can't remember the exact exception or message) in a custom IServerChannelSink I wrote to get additional data from the client via the headers. I've modified my code as such so that when an exception is thrown, the exception is handled (prior to the modification there was no try/catch block):

```
  public ServerProcessing ProcessMessage(
          IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack,
          IMessage requestMsg,
          ITransportHeaders requestHeaders,
          Stream requestStream,
          out IMessage responseMsg,
          out ITransportHeaders responseHeaders,
          out Stream responseStream)
  {
     // example of retrieving data from the client via the header, the client IP Address
     IPAddress ip = requestHeaders[CommonTransportKeys.IPAddress] as IPAddress;
     CallContext.SetData("ClientIPAddress", ip);

     ServerProcessing? spres = null;
     IMessage lResponseMsg = null;
     ITransportHeaders lResponseHeaders = null;
     Stream lResponseStream = null;

     try
     {
        // _nextSink is a member object which is set in the constructor, or in the NextSink property
        if (_nextSink != null)
        {
           spres = _nextSink.ProcessMessage(
              sinkStack,
              requestMsg,
              requestHeaders,
              requestStream,
              out lResponseMsg,
              out lResponseHeaders,
              out lResponseStream);
        }
     }
     catch { }
     finally
     {
        responseMsg = lResponseMsg;
        responseHeaders = lResponseHeaders;
        responseStream = lResponseStream;
     }

     return (spres != null) ? (ServerProcessing)spres : ServerProcessing.Complete;
  }
```

However, I'm not sure that leaving responseMsg, responseHeaders, or responseStream as null is the correct way to handle this in the event that _nextSink.ProcessMessage throws an exception. It fixes the exception being thrown server side, but I don't know how this will affect the client receiving the response parameters. I've seen other examples for HTTP server sink providers that suggest to set the header as a '400 Bad Request', but our protocol is TCP and I don't believe that setting the TCP header to an HTTP compatible value is the right way to handle this either.

What is the proper way of handling errors that occur within an implementation of IServerChannelSink.ProcessMessage? Additionally, any guides or explanations on implementing your own IServerChannelSink are welcome as well, as I wrote most of this class based on a couple other questions I've asked on SO while otherwise flying blind.

***EDIT***: I've looked at examples from MSDN's IServerChannelSink section, but I don't trust it since they do things I know aren't supposed to happen in the implementation class (e.g. throwing unhandled exceptions)

Runtime: .NET 4

Language: C#

Protocol: TCP (.NET Remoting)